# Does Lucio's Sonic Amplifier Knock Back Distance Vary By Proximity?

Tags: overwatch

When playing against Lúcio, sometimes it seems I only get knocked back a little bit, other times it seem like I go flying. I haven't noticed much difference when playing, but I don't really notice a difference in how far I knock them away from me, however I try not to get too close to people in order to stay safe. Does the distance away from the target effect the distance I knock the target back when using alternate fire with sonic amplifier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Testing it with Lucio on the training stage:

- I tested it on this spot with the Lucio spray.

[image]

- After each trial, I moved one step back, further and further until his sonic amplifier would no longer knock them back.
- Although I tested it from different distances (taking one step back from the spray every trial), the areas in which the bots landed always landed on the same line starting with the first target. The line is highlighted in red.

[image]

- Using speed amplifier or speed boost did not affect how much further it flew.  Even using the speed boost ability the bot landed exactly on a point on the red line in the screenshot above.
- This leads me to believe that regardless how far you are from the opponent they will always fly a set distance.
- When testing on different heroes in a custom game, lighter heroes like Tracer, Genji, and Widowmaker tended to fly further than big-boned heroes like Roadhog and Reinhardt

Comment: Does adjusting your aim help get stronger/longer knock backs? For example, looking up at an angle instead of straight in front of you or downwards.

Comment: your 3rd bullet point is somewhat confusing to me. could you perhaps reword it?

Comment: I'm super confused. You say they land at the same spot every time, and then say that how far they fly depends on where you stand. These are contradictory statements.

Comment: @O-O No, if they are standing in the same spot and land in the same spot then they fly the same distance. How far they are from you when you fire isn't part of the distance they fly.

Comment: Fixed the bullet points

Comment: "This meant that the further back I used my ability, the further they flew." "This leads me to believe that regardless how far you are from the opponent they will always fly a set distance." This doesn't seem fixed, I'm still very confused...

Comment: @ShadyBaby I was corrected earlier by DCshannon, looks like I skipped that part as well

Comment: Character weight/size doesn't seem to effect the distance: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1Bw3MXaLo4&feature=youtu.be